# QQ-plot using Plotly in Python

Tags: python, plotly

Is there a standard, effective way of producing a QQ-Plot using Plotly?

I would be interested in testing the normal/log-normal fit of my data.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Alright, here is how I think the state of affairs is now [**2020 edit**]:

Say we have 500 random draws from a distribution which we think might be the lognormal distribution:

```py
X_lognorm = np.random.lognormal(mean=0.0, sigma=1.7, size=500)
```

**Plotting**

Imports

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import plotly.graph_objects as go
```

Run plotly

```py
qq = stats.probplot(X_lognorm, dist='lognorm', sparams=(1))
x = np.array([qq[0][0][0], qq[0][0][-1]])

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_scatter(x=qq[0][0], y=qq[0][1], mode='markers')
fig.add_scatter(x=x, y=qq[1][1] + qq[1][0]*x, mode='lines')
fig.layout.update(showlegend=False)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I applied this to a `plotly dash` script but I had to make the figure as a `go.Figure` object. That is, instead of `fig = dict(data=data, layout=layout)` I had `fig = go.Figure(data, layout=layout) `.

Comment: Things have changed since 2018 :) I have updated the code (not the plot though). It's much simpler now.

Comment: Hey, the docs say "probplot generates a probability plot, which should not be confused with a Q-Q or a P-P plot. Statsmodels has more extensive functionality of this type, see statsmodels.api.ProbPlot" which might be worth bearing in mind if you explicitly want a qq plot (docs = https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.probplot.html)